# Почему input textare не получает данные?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, react-hook, react-hook-form

Я использую для формы **react-hook-form**. Мне нужно получить данные из **input textarea**, но объект получает пустой **teaxtarea**. В чем проблема и как исправить?

```
const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors }, reset } = useForm({
defaultValues: {
  firstName: "",
  weight: "",
  age: "",
  email: "",
  telephone: "",
  radio: "",
  textarea: "",
},
mode: "onBlur",
resolver: yupResolver(schema),
});
```

```js
import React, { forwardRef } from "react";

import "./styles.scss";

export const Textarea = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return <input ref={ref} {...props} />;
});
```

```
<Textarea
  {...register("textarea")}
  type="typearea"
  id="comment"
  htmlFor="comment"
  name="comment"
  placeholder="Расскажите обо всех подвадках кота"
  className="form-input-textarea"
/>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`register("textarea")` дает объект с 4-мя свойствами https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register#main

```
{
  onChange: void,
  onBlur: void,
  ref: node,
  name: 'textarea',
}
```

Проблема в ключе `name` со значением `textarea`. Через деструктуризацию ты ее передаешь в компонент `Textarea`, но потом добавляешь проп `name="comment"` и переписываешь. Попробуй убрать этот проп.